# NameError: undefined nested function in python

Tags: python

I'm a python beginner, I'm trying to reorganize my code, I have multiple nested functions 
Here is my python code

```
def download_pkg(self):
    (...)

def download_several_apps(self):
    global inputFileName_download,listbox_input

    if(listbox_input.size() == 0):
        print("NO INPUT FILE")
    elif(listbox_input.size() == 1):
        print("filename :" + str(self.inputFileName_download))

        with open(self.inputFileName_download, 'r') as f:
            for line in  f:
                print(line)
                download_pkg(line)
    else:
        print("Problem while downloading several apps")
```

I have this error :

> NameError: name 'download_pkg' is not defined

How can I access this function ? Thank you

Comment: `listbox_input` (or rather, its `size` attribute) should be an argument to `download_several_apps`, not a global; `inputFileName_download` is *already* an instance attribute; you aren't using any global by that name (if one even exists).

Answer (score 4):

You don't show it, but you're clearly in a class's methods, not top-level functions. So you need to call the method on an existing instance of the class. Luckily, you're an instance method yourself, so you have `self` available to do so. Just change:

```
download_pkg(line)
```

to:

```
self.download_pkg(line)
```

Comment: ok I understand the proble, I have an other error : TypeError: download_pkg() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @userHG: You're the one who passed it `line`. I have no idea what it's supposed to do with `line`, but if it's supposed to take a (non-`self`) argument, you'll need to receive an extra argument (aside from `self`) on `download_pkg`.